# Passing the value of state using setParams and getParam to other Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I use `componentWillMount()` because I think it's impossible to use `static` to use setParams with the state and also the `GalleryScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {}` outside the `class` of `React.Component`.

I've been trying to use this method but I always get the error of:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.state.params.imageData')

My outcome is to pass the value of `state.pickedImage` from GalleryScreen.js to EventInput.js inside return statement.

GalleyScreen.js : This is React Component

```
 componentWillMount() {
    const {setParams} = this.props.navigation;
    setParams({imageData: this.state.pickedImage})
}
```

EventInput.js : This is only EventInput props (not React Component)

```
const EventInput = props => {
const [titleValue, setTitleValue] = useState('');
const [descriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState('');

// const imageData = props.navigation.getParam('imageData');

const events = useSelector(state => state.events.events);

const titleChangeHandler = (title) => {
    setTitleValue(title);
};

const descriptionChangeHandler = (description) => {
    setDescriptionValue(description);
};

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='transparent' translucent barStyle='dark-content'/>
        <Text>Event Input</Text>
        <TextInput 
            placeholder="Enter title..."
            onChangeText={titleChangeHandler}
        />
        <TextInput 
            placeholder="Enter description..."
            onChangeText={descriptionChangeHandler}
        />
        <Image source={{uri: props.navigation.state.params.imageData}} style={{width: 300, height: 300}}/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.navigate('SetEventLocation', {
                eventTitle: titleValue,
                eventDescription: descriptionValue
            })
        }}>
            <Text>Next</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);
};

export default withNavigation(EventInput);
```

Is there any alternative solution so I can pass the value of my `state.pickedImage`? and use `getParam` to get the value of it from other Component?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to pass params to `navigationOptions` or another component?

Comment: Another component, I want to pass it from GalleryScreen.js to EventInput.js inside return statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access navigation, you should wrap your component with "withNavigation".

[More details here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html)

Comment: could you share code of EventInput.js? is it a stateless function or just a function?

Comment: thank you, you can get ImageData by this way:   props.navigation.getParam("imageData")

Comment: doesn't work. To make it sure it does not work I change the value to text and display it to text but still no luck.

Comment: did you pass navigation prop to EventInput? you can check this link how to do it. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2115#issuecomment-314291423